# Taste of coffee that has not rested long enough

Tags: roasting, home-roasting, cup, tasting, resting

There is a lot of speculation about how long to allow coffee to rest after roasting prior to cupping, see [this post](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/roast-profile-vs-rest-time-any-connection) and [this post](http://here), and it has been discussed at length at home barista and other places too. But how would you describe the flavor of coffee that has not had adequate resting time? From experience with a particular bean generally roasted to City it seems that the flavor is tainted at 2 days. It is a much cleaner cup after 3-4 days. But I have trouble describing that particular flavor in SCAA terms other than "taint". It seems to be vaguely salty + a lot of something else very destinctive that I can not describe. I would like to be able to detect and describe that flavor when I move to another bean and profile to be able to better know whether the profile/batch was a dud or I need to recup in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the more likely result of insufficient "rest time" is a lack of flavor. It tastes like coffee, but without enough depth of flavor. In that case, I will simply let it rest for two days, then try the coffee again. Usually there is a noticeable improvement.

In some cases, the flavor will not improve with more rest. That means that I did not roast the bean far enough. So I make a note to roast a bit longer (10 to 15 seconds) next time.

Comment: So would you say it is then a bit herby or green?

Comment: @Nick not really any specific flavor